# How to compile .java file in war directory of eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, applet

I am creating a web application project to deploy in GAE. I have the servlet in the src folder. The welcome page is a html file, index.html, that invokes a client side applet, Client.java. I have placed the .java file in war directory next to index.html.

Now, if I want to invoke the applet code in html file I need the .class version of it. However, Eclipse automatically compiles only the java file in src folder. How do I compile the Client.java file in Eclipse?

Comment: You need to put all your java code in the src folder, that includes Client.java.  If you've configured your web app properly, the class files will end up in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: I suspect those areas you see the class file in, are not even *available* to a client browser (or therefore a client JVM).  Check it by trying to load the class file directly.  Note also that in this day and age, an applet will need to be in a jar signed with a valid signature, to have much hope of making it onto screen.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

Your applet class should reside in its own project, separate from your WAR project. Applets are more like standalone projects and built differently than a web app. They also have their own dependencies, need to be signed, etc.

After the applet is built you either transfer it manually in a web accessible folder of your web app (lets say /lib) OR you automate this in your build routine (gradle, maven, ant, etc).